# UIButton can not receive event in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uibutton

I use the code snippet below to create my UIScrollView:

```
    scrollView = [[CustomScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 737);
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [_scrollView addSubview:myView];
```

CustomScrollView is subclass of UIScrollView.
myView is a UIVIew from .xib and there is a UIButton in myView.

The issue is: When the Y position of the UIButton is smaller than 568, it can receive touch events, but when it's larger than 568, for example, 680, it fails to response any touch event.

SDK is iOS8.1.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How big is myView? If myView is not big enough, it may fail to respond to touch events.

Comment: Size of myView is "Inferred" and in my iPhone it's 320*568. It's created from IB. Do I need to set a larger Y?

Comment: Your myView isn't big enough. The button is actually outside myView. The button will show up, but can't respond to touch event. Because its touch event is actually passed from myView. And myView have to be big enough to have enough responding area.